# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_rxjs.queueScheduler.constructor')

Tags: ios, react-native, react-redux, ipa

We have developed a react-native application using react-redux in ubuntu. We are trying to build an IPA from a mac system using the same code.but we are unable to run the application and getting an error in the simulator

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try
npm install rxjs,
rjs node module missing